# When forking MainNet with ganache-cli and trying to interact with contract -> error thrown

Tags: contract-development, truffle, forks, ganache-cli, defi

Forked MainNet with Ganache-ClI

wrote script to interact with on-chain DAI contract to send some Dai to account

Unlocked the DAI contract

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const daiAbi = require('/Users/GreyShadow/inbox/ganache-cli.Fork/daiABI.js');

const recipientAddress = "0x1418D9353E655d277009E08aD882442B6e23F07D";
const unlockedAddress = "0xd4405F0704621DBe9d4dEA60E128E0C3b26bddbD";
const daiAdress = "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F";
const web3 = new Web3(`http://localhost:8545`);
const dai = new web3.eth.Contract(
  daiAbi,
  daiAdress
);

async function run() {
  let unlockedBalance, recipientBalance;
  ([unlockedBalance, recipientBalance] = await Promise.all
    ([
      dai.methods
        .balanceOf(unlockedAddress)
        .call (),
      dai.methods
        .balanceOf(recipientAddress)
        .call()
    ]));
    console.log('Balance unlocked: ${unlockedBalance}');
    console.log('Balance recipient: ${recipientBalance}');

    await dai.methods
      .transfer(recipientAddress, 1000)
      .send({from: unlockedAddress});

      ([unlockedBalance, recipientBalance] = await Promise.all ([
        dai.methods
          .balanceOf(unlockedAddress)
          .call()
      ]));
      console.log('Balance unlcoked: ${unlockedBalance}');
      console.log('Balance recipient: ${recipientBalance}');
}
run ();
```

when running node script.js following error is shown

```
/Users/GreyShadow/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:61
        throw errors.ContractMissingABIError();
        ^

Error: You must provide the json interface of the contract when instantiating a contract object.
```

ABI is in that directory and should be required/recognized.

Any help would be much appreciated

P.S

Comment: "`ABI is in that directory and should be required/recognized`" - that's in **your directory**, not **ours**! Please open that file and make sure that it exports a proper ABI object. If you're not sure whether or not it does, then please post a short version of its contents as part of your question.

Comment: By the way, ABI objects are usually given in a JSON file, which you should `fs.readFileSync` and then `JSON.parse` (in opposed to requiring a JS file as you seem to be doing).

Comment: But since you've placed that ABI object in a JS file, you must `module.exports` this object inside that JS file in order to be able to `require` it.

Comment: If you just copied it from a JSON file into a JS file, then note that it doesn't "magically" turn into JS code, and neither will requiring that file turn it into JS code. You need to do that yourself (as I explained above, declare it as an object in that file, and then `module.exports` it).

Comment: Hey goodvibration. I get where youre coming from, however not quite sure on how to implement it. Something like this?   ```                                                                                         const daiABI = artifacts.require("daiABI");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(daiABI);
};````

Comment: If you're not running this inside a Truffle environment (test or migration), then you don't have such thing as `artifacts` at your disposal. If you **are** running this inside a Truffle environment, then you shouldn't be using `new web3.eth.Contract` to begin with. Which one is it???

Comment: We are not using a truffle environment. Do you mean something like this?: module.exports = require(/Users/GreyShadow/inbox/ganache-cli.Fork/daiABI.js);

Comment: No, I mean that you should probably put `module.exports =` **inside that file**, but again - I have no way of telling without seeing its actual contents (which is the very first thing in this conversation that I asked you to provide). BTW, this issue has nothing to do with Ethereum. It is strictly about something in Javascript that you are not doing correctly. It might be useful for you to read a little about NodeJS `require` statement, and understand how it works.

Comment: Right sorry the Abi is copied from etherscan Dai StableCoin contract.  gonna read about require statements. thought id already understand it but obviously...

Comment: If you copy that into a file named 'daiAbi.json', then you should simply do `const daiAbi = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("daiAbi.json", {encoding: "utf8"}));`.

Comment: Alternatively (though probably less comfortable for you), you can do `const daiAbi = PasteTheAbiFromEtherscanHere;`. Less comfortable, because you'll that very long line of code in your script... Maybe it's actually more comfortable, because you don't need another file... your call...

Comment: thanks for the help. Worked with ```module.exports =``` inside the .json file

Comment: You mean, inside the JS file.

Comment: Yeah thats what i meant...